# mysql server is not starting

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, my.cnf

mysql server is not starting after modifying configurations

```
key_buffer      = 16M
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
query_cache_size    = 16M
```

after change ->

```
key_buffer_size = 384M
max_allowed_packet = 1M
table_open_cache = 512
sort_buffer_size = 2M
read_buffer_size = 2M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 8M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 64M
thread_cache_size = 8
query_cache_size = 32M



innodb_buffer_pool_size = 375M
```

after change ->

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 384M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 20M

# Set .._log_file_size to 25 % of buffer pool size

innodb_log_file_size = 100M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M

#innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
#innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50
```

configuration -> my.cnf

```
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
# 
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

# This will be passed to all mysql clients
# It has been reported that passwords should be enclosed with ticks/quotes
# escpecially if they contain "#" chars...
# Remember to edit /etc/mysql/debian.cnf when changing the socket location.
[client]
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

# Here is entries for some specific programs
# The following values assume you have at least 32M ram

# This was formally known as [safe_mysqld]. Both versions are currently parsed.
[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0

[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address        = 127.0.0.1
#
# * Fine Tuning
#

key_buffer_size = 384M
max_allowed_packet = 1M
table_open_cache = 512
sort_buffer_size = 2M
read_buffer_size = 2M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 8M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 64M
thread_cache_size = 8
query_cache_size = 32M
# Try number of CPU's*2 for thread_concurrency
#thread_concurrency = 8

query_cache_limit   = 10M
query_cache_size        = 16M

#
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
#general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#general_log             = 1
#
# Error log - should be very few entries.
#
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
#
# Here you can see queries with especially long duration
#log_slow_queries   = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
#long_query_time = 2
#log-queries-not-using-indexes
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.
#server-id      = 1
#log_bin            = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M
#binlog_do_db       = include_database_name
#binlog_ignore_db   = include_database_name
#
# * InnoDB
#
# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!


#innodb_data_home_dir = /var/lib/mysql
#innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:2000M;ibdata2:10M:autoextend
#innodb_log_group_home_dir = /var/lib/mysql
# You can set .._buffer_pool_size up to 50 - 80 %
# of RAM but beware of setting memory usage too high

innodb_buffer_pool_size = 384M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 20M

# Set .._log_file_size to 25 % of buffer pool size

innodb_log_file_size = 100M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M

#innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
#innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50


#    #



#
# * Security Features
#
# Read the manual, too, if you want chroot!
# chroot = /var/lib/mysql/
#
# For generating SSL certificates I recommend the OpenSSL GUI "tinyca".
#
# ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/cacert.pem
# ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
# ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem



[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet  = 16M

[mysql]
#no-auto-rehash # faster start of mysql but no tab completition

[isamchk]
key_buffer      = 16M

#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/

140725 10:33:07 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-      recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
140725 10:33:07 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
140725 10:33:07 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
140725 10:33:07 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
140725 10:33:07 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
140725 10:33:07 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
140725 10:33:07 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 375.0M
140725 10:33:07 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
140725 10:33:07 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
140725 10:33:07  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
140725 10:33:08 InnoDB: 5.5.38 started; log sequence number 1224364093
140725 10:33:08 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.0.0.1'; port: 3306
140725 10:33:08 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
140725 10:33:08 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
140725 10:33:08 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
140725 10:33:08 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.38-0ubuntu0.14.04.1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu)
140725 10:33:57 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Normal shutdown

140725 10:33:57 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
140725 10:33:57  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
140725 10:33:57  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1224364093
140725 10:33:57 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

140725 10:40:16 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
140725 10:40:16 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
140725 10:40:16 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
140725 10:40:16 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
140725 10:40:16 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
140725 10:40:16 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 384.0M
140725 10:40:16 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: Error: log file ./ib_logfile0 is of different size 0 5242880 bytes
InnoDB: than specified in the .cnf file 0 104857600 bytes!
140725 10:40:16 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
140725 10:40:16 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
140725 10:40:16 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
140725 10:40:16 [ERROR] Aborting

140725 10:40:16 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

140725 10:40:17 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
140725 10:40:17 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
140725 10:40:17 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
140725 10:40:17 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
140725 10:40:17 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
140725 10:40:17 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 384.0M
140725 10:40:17 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
```

InnoDB: Error: log file ./ib_logfile0 is of different size 0 5242880 bytes
InnoDB: than specified in the .cnf file 0 104857600 bytes!
    140725 10:40:17 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
    140725 10:40:17 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
    140725 10:40:17 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
    140725 10:40:17 [ERROR] Aborting

```
140725 10:40:17 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

140725 10:40:18 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
140725 10:40:18 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
140725 10:40:18 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
140725 10:40:18 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
140725 10:40:18 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
140725 10:40:18 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 384.0M
140725 10:40:18 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: Error: log file ./ib_logfile0 is of different size 0 5242880 bytes
InnoDB: than specified in the .cnf file 0 104857600 bytes!
140725 10:40:18 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
140725 10:40:18 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
140725 10:40:18 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
140725 10:40:18 [ERROR] Aborting

140725 10:40:18 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

140725 10:48:07 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
140725 10:48:07 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
140725 10:48:07 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
140725 10:48:07 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
140725 10:48:07 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
140725 10:48:07 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
140725 10:48:07 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 375.0M
140725 10:48:07 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
140725 10:48:07 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
140725 10:48:07  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
140725 10:48:08 InnoDB: 5.5.38 started; log sequence number 1224364093
140725 10:48:08 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.0.0.1'; port: 3306
140725 10:48:08 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
140725 10:48:08 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
140725 10:48:08 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
140725 10:48:08 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.38-0ubuntu0.14.04.1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu)
```

Comment: What did you change? What errors are you getting, including in the server log?

Comment: i have added changes @Mat

Comment: Did you at least do a quick google for that error message?

Comment: @Mat I'm new to Mysql don't know what line causing it so, i can do search on google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You changed the `innodb_log_file_size` and, as you are not using 5.6 (where that is handled automatically), you have to delete manually `ib_logfile0` and `ib_logfile1` when MySQL is stopped for InnoDB to recreate them with the new size on start.

Make sure you do a clean shutdown before doing all that, not a crash / `innodb_fast_shutdown = 2`.

Comment: it solved the issue thnx.

Comment: any idea why count query too slow. SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `perfectlocal`.`businesses` AS `Business` LEFT JOIN `perfectlocal`.`postal` AS `Postal` ON (`Business`.`postal_id` = `Postal`.`id`) LEFT JOIN `perfectlocal`.`businesses_categories` AS `BusinessesCategory` ON (`Business`.`id` = `BusinessesCategory`.`business_id`) LEFT JOIN `perfectlocal`.`categories` AS `Category` ON (`BusinessesCategory`.`category_id` = `Category`.`id`) WHERE `Category`.`category_slug` = 'restaurants' AND `Business`.`address_locality` = 'montreal'

Comment: I recommend you creating a different question and linking it here, the formatting is unreadable. Cheers.

Comment: how to do that ?